# How to Pass Value between wp forms text field form one page to another Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wpforms

I'm trying to pass value from the text field in WP forms to another page text field, i have no code can someone help me or make a PHP code for this passing value?

need to pass value from the text field in WP forms to another page text field, i have no code can someone help me or make a PHP code for this passing value?